# SXA 1.6 - Dynamic search scope

Tags: sxa

Using SXA 1.6 we have the requirement to allow the content editor to select articles with specific tags; these tags are editable by the content editor, is there a user friendly way to do so without the need to define them in search scope as it will be difficult for the content editor to manage them?

Comment: Without modifying the sope it's not possible. But you can prepare some predefined scopes and editor would need only to change the scope (if you have the predefined list of tags or at least static enough so that you could add additional scopes if needed)